# How does MDM lock the device?

Tags: android, android-security

I want to build a custom anti-thief Android MDM. One of the main features is - remotely locking device and changing it's lock screen passcode.

But in that scenario, user can just perform a factory reset (or even wipe the partition and reinstall a different ROM). Is there a way of protecting the phone from that? Is it even possible to remotely lock the device so that a thief cannot do anything?

I've spoken to representatives of some MDM solutions, they all claim that their products give 100% security. But how do they achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. The only real way one could do this is a full remote wipe. And some type of random encryption code that's set like when you start the phone? But to be honest the only real thing you could do is fry the phone remotely?

I don't really think there is a full 100% way of stopping thevies. Unless you could preform a type of ransomwear? That locks the phone in everyway.

Comment: Usually, a ransomware could be 'disabled' by a simple factory reset. Or no?

Comment: Not if you could some how get a hook into system files. Or managed to disable or block to code connected to the hardware buttons? It's an interesting question but I think it's got to broad of an awnser really. Besides I don't imagine these companies just hand out their app ideas. I mean if you really want to you could dig around the apks. Decompile read some code?